# Equivalent of HTML5 Context Menus now

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

I need html5 feature [Context Menu](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-context-menu). Now only FF [supports](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contextmenu.asp) it. The main goal is to **add** some menu options, I do **not** want to replace the existing context menu.

So, how can I have the same functionality today? I know there are a lot of [jquery context menu plugins](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-context-menu/page/2/) but seems all of them **replace** context menu completely.

Comment: you simply can't. the closest is to use something like [Shift]+rightClick to show your menu _instead_ of the default context menu.

Comment: @dandavis I thought the same, just wanted to confirm. I may not know something

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. I used https://plugins.jquery.com/contextMenu/. Its much simple than other plugins. I couldn't find any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you sure that it allows to **keep default** context menu and add some more options? From my experience it removes default context menu